# Python - pytesseract not consistent for similar images

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

For example this image returns Sieteary ear

[image]

While this image returns the correct answer

[image]

The only difference between the 2 images is 2 pixels in the height.

I have tried applying some threshold but didnt seem to help...

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
image = Image.open(path)
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng'))
```

Comment: What kind of answer are you hoping for?

Comment: What image processing should i do to fix this inconsistency

Comment: The difference is not just the two pixels: different jpeg compression artifacts are visible around the characters which are presumably affecting tesseract OCR. You should binarize to black text on white background to get best results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform some preprocessing using OpenCV. The idea is to [enlarge the image with imutils](https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils#resizing), obtain a binary image using Otsu's threshold, then add a slight Gaussian blur. For optimal detection, the image should be in the form where desired text to be detected is in black with the background in white. Here's the preprocessing results for the two images:

Before `->` After

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

The output result from Pytesseract for both images are the same

```
BigBootyHunter2
```

Code

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import imutils

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
image = imutils.resize(image, width=500)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
thresh = cv2.GaussianBlur(thresh, (3,3), 0)
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh, lang='eng',config='--psm 6')
print(data)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Didn't think about the resizing option. Thank you very much!